# Norman Antivirus corporate virus log file

Tags: anti-virus

Does the Norman Antivirus corporate edition log virus detections in a central place? It currently sends out virus emails, but that is not so good for parsing the log files.
My desired end result would be to be able to see detections or a per user or machine level. And see what % XX virus is of current detections.

Comment: Are you sure you mean "Norman Anti-Virus" and not "Norton Anti-Virus"?.... I understand there is a Norman Corporate Edition solution for security (AV/Spyware/etc..), but had to ask as some might be confused.  http://www.norman.com/enterprise/all_bundles/norman_corporate_edition/en-us

Comment: Yes its not norton.

Comment: I thought so, someone had replaced all the 'norman' parts with 'norton' :)... I put it back as it was.

Comment: my bad, I didn't realize "Norman Antivirus" was a .. a .. thing. I thought it was like buying "Rorex" fake Rolex watches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I was unable to find a solution for this, I ended up writing a parser for the emails (after they where exported to CSV files).
If anyone else wants a solution to this, contact me and I'll publish the application.